# Can't display image in Opencv cause memory location

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019

Im trying to display an image with opencv but failed. Search google and don't know how the closest one show a debug only

Here the code

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("dom.png");
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("image", img);// It stuck here
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to put img in Resource File and Source File but still get error. The platform is for x64 .

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBE404A388 in Opencv_01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000768258F1B0.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBE404A388 in Opencv_01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000768258F1B0.
```

Where have I go wrong?

Comment: Most likely, your file `dom.png` isn't placed in the working directory, where you start your program. The error message than just tells you, that the `img` variable is no proper `cv::Mat` to be displayed. For a quick test, just use the absolute path to your `dom.png` image file.

Comment: @HansHirse Could you tell me where should I place in the working directory. It look like this [link](http://prntscr.com/pm4p29)

Comment: Never worked with _Resource Files_. For general information on working directories, especially when using Visual Studio, there should be plenty of tutorials available.

Comment: Just try to go to properties of your image and copy the directory from there. Then replace in your code with "dom.png". Because in my opinion, the directory is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not handle the case where if fails to load the image. Perhaps it's not found in the currnet directory of the program.

The way to check that the image was loaded is like this:

```
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("dom.png");

    if(!img.data) {
        cout << "Could not load image" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("image", img);// It stuck here
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```